# App crashes but foreground service is still running

Tags: java, android, task, bluetooth-lowenergy, foreground-service

I'm using a foreground-bound service that provides Bluetooth capabilities to my app. When the app crashes, the service is still bound. So, `onServiceDisconnected()` will not be triggered. The app is dead, but the service is still running underneath.

Of course, a sudden app crash doesn't give me a chance to call the unbind method. And what happens is that the service is still running ignoring the dead app beneath.

Is anyone facing the same issue or maybe found a workaround to manage the event?

Is the service capable of searching trough the task list for its own application and understand if the app is alive or not?

Comment: I think you need to identify the reason for crash first.

Comment: service is working on another process?

Comment: It is not a particular crash that bothers me, it was more a general thought. Crash could happen.

Comment: service will be dead too, if process gonna be killed. so the question still, is your service working in another process?

Comment: it shouldn't . There's an easy way to check it?

Comment: Andrew, it seems that you're right. I started the app through the debugger. The service started. I manually closed the app but the debugger is still connected.

Comment: Even if i call stopservice and unbindservice, when i close the app, the debugger remains connected and so the service.

Comment: I'm calling bindService(scanService, mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE) exactly 1 time and the same goes for stopService(scanService);
        unbindService(mConnection); I dunno how i'm creating multiple bonding